# How to use two parameters that Facebook retrieve to me

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-login

I'm doing login with Facebook now I have the info but I want to use two values of the dictResponse to use them later those values are "name" and "email" but I don't know how can I save them in a variable or constant. Could you help me. Please.

This is my code:

```
 func getFBUserData(){
        if((FBSDKAccessToken.current()) != nil){
            FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                if (error == nil){
                    self.dictResponse = result as! [String : AnyObject]

                    print(result!)
                    print(self.dictResponse)
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

And this is the service response

```
email = "xxxxxxxx@outlook.com";
    "first_name" =xxxxx;
    id =0000000000000;
    "last_name" = "xxxxxxx";
    name = "xxxxxxxxx";
    picture =     {
        data =         {
            "is_silhouette" = 0;
            url = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        };
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add Preferences struct with singltone object

```
struct Preferences {

    //singlton
    static var shared = Preferences() 

    var name: String?
    var email: String?
}
```

and store your variables there

```
func getFBUserData(){
        if((FBSDKAccessToken.current()) != nil){
            FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                if (error == nil){
                    self.dictResponse = result as! [String : AnyObject]
                    Preferences.shared.name = dictResponse["name"] as? String
                    Preferences.shared.email = dictResponse["email"] as? String

                    print(result!)
                    print(self.dictResponse)
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

in future you can get them from wherever.

Comment: If my answer helped you can you please upvote it and mark as right answer :) thanks

Comment: Sure, I would like to do that but I Don't have less than 15 reputation but YES IT HELP'S ME A LOT THANKS  :)